# Can I get bash completion to consider the text _after_ the cursor?

Tags: bash, bash-completion

Motivating example:

I'm in a shell session in some directory, and I have three files: `prefix_foo_suffix.txt`, `prefix_bar_suffix.txt` and `prefix_bar_another_suffix.txt`. I've typed in: `cat prefix_foo_suffix.txt`, but I've changed my mind, I want the second file. So, I delete `foo`, and write `b` - only to realize I'veforgotten the name of that second file. So now my command-line is `cat prefix_b_suffix.txt` with the cursor after the `b`.

Now, if I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, completion kicks in, but it gives me: `prefix_bar_suffix.txt_suffix.txt` which is not what I wanted.

Is it possible to get bash to consider the rest of the current word, or line, for completion? i.e. complete intra-word substrings to reach a relevant word?

Comment: `Is it possible` yes, it is possible to "consider".  In `COMP_LINE` you have the whole line, you can break it, extract the word at `COMP_POINT` cursor position and complete. You could post such patch upstream to bash-completion project and see what happens.

Comment: you could hit alt + d after you type b to delete _suffix.txt this will remove everything until the next space so if you have other parameters it wont delete them

Comment: @Orion: Tweaked my example to make it actually useful to use the suffix.